# Why crash on close when loading HTML using MapBox with QTWebengineview?

Tags: qt, pyqt5, mapbox, mapbox-gl, qtwebengine

A collision occurred while displaying a map of MapBox using QTWebEngineView.
Previously, Google Maps and Ice Maps were displayed, but they worked well without problems.

If you try to display MapBox's Map on QtWebenegineVIew, exit without any error logs the moment MapBox is about to display.

PyQt5 Version : 5.15.5
PyQt5 WebEngineView Version : 5.15.1
MapBoxgl Version : 1.13.0

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


class CustomWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.__init_widget()

    def __init_widget(self):
        try:
            mapbox_html_path = "<HTML-PATH>"

            self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
            self.map_widget = QWebEngineView()
            self.map_widget.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
            self.map_widget.load(QUrl.fromLocalFile(mapbox_html_path))

            self.dev_tool = QWebEngineView()
            self.map_widget.page().setDevToolsPage(self.dev_tool.page())
            self.dev_tool.show()

            self.layout.addWidget(self.map_widget)

            self.setLayout(self.layout)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create("Fusion"))
    app.setAttribute(Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling, True)

    custom_widget = CustomWidget()
    custom_widget.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.13.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.13.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map" style="position:relative;width:400px;height:400px;"></div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            style: {
                version: 8,
                sources: {
                    'raster-tiles': {
                        type: 'raster',
                        tiles: [
                            'http://ak.dynamic.t0.tiles.virtualearth.net/comp/ch/{quadkey}?mkt=ko&it=G,L&shading=hill&og=1679&n=z',
                            'http://ak.dynamic.t1.tiles.virtualearth.net/comp/ch/{quadkey}?mkt=ko&it=G,L&shading=hill&og=1679&n=z', 
                            'http://ak.dynamic.t2.tiles.virtualearth.net/comp/ch/{quadkey}?mkt=ko&it=G,L&shading=hill&og=1679&n=z',
                            'http://ak.dynamic.t3.tiles.virtualearth.net/comp/ch/{quadkey}?mkt=ko&it=G,L&shading=hill&og=1679&n=z'
                        ],
                    }
                },
                layers: [
                    {
                        id: 'simple-tiles',
                        type: 'raster',
                        source: 'raster-tiles',
                        minzoom: 0,
                        maxzoom: 22,
                    },
                ],
            },
            center: [126.64846045343421, 37.36657719850406],
            zoom: 10,
            hash: true,
            container: 'map'
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can you normally display MapBox's Map on QtWebEngineView?

---

I Solved This Problem.

The problem was solved by using setHtml without using setUrl.
However, I am not sure why it was resolved.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. Please specify OS, python and PyQt versions you're using.

Comment: version update complete

Comment: I Solved This Problem.

The problem was solved by using setHtml without using setUrl. However, I am not sure why it was resolved.

Comment: Version 1.15.5 for PyQt seems unlikely.

Comment: Sorry, PYQT Version : 5.15.5